# Java REST call gives different response from eclipse and jar execution

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven

I have a piece of code that fetches some data using REST call

The string I'm pulling via REST has some chinese characters in it

1.Select 詳細規格配備

Now, when I run the code as a Java Application from eclipse, I get the data perfectly in the output console(System.out.println)

However, when I run make a jar of the same code using maven, and run the jar (java -jar ), these chinese characters change into å…§è£é¡è‰²

I even migrated the code to a different system, believing it could be an issue with the libraries, but the result is still the same.

any ideas what might be going wrong when the code is being executed from the jar ?

I'm using maven's assembly plugin to build jar with dependencies

Thank you.

Comment: Its encoding issue. You need UTF-8 encoding to see the characters.

Comment: I get that, but how come it is working fine in eclipse IDE?
That's my only concern.
Anything to do with the JRE version being used or something..

Comment: It is working in eclipse IDE, because you are seeing the ouput in the IDE console which is properly set to view UTF-8 character. Your data is all same. If you want to be sure about that, you can write your response to a text file and see what happen. Without proper encoding, the data will be written incorrectly.